# With cakephp2.3 and mongoDB how to add array in a document?

Tags: mongodb, cakephp-2.3

how can I work with lists within the mongoDB?

For example, I have a document (class), and a list of students in this class, ie a subdocument (students).
  What do not you, is to add more students to a class.

in Model:

```
public function salvar($name,$idClass){

 $new = array(     
   "_id" => $idClass,
   "student"=>  array(
                        'idStudent' => new MongoId(),
                        'name' => $name));

  return $this->save($new);
    }
```

But when you add a new student, he is not working that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to perform a $push update

The answer you've provided clarifies what you've been trying to do. However, the solution is a little convoluted. To perform a `$push` update with MongoDB, simply specify you want to perform a push update:

```
$this->Foo->save(array( 
    '_id' => $id,
    '$push' => array(
        "images" => array(
            'id' => new MongoId(),
            'name' => $name,
            'size' => $size
        )
     )
);
```

You *can* use the `mongoNoSetOperator` property to achieve the same thing but

1. It's indirect, therefore not obvious
2. With multiple calls to save in the same request it can be confusing if it's not reset to `$set` if it's modified
3. It prevents using multiple operators in a single call.

There's more information about using different update operators in [the documentation](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/wiki/How-to-use-MongoDB-update-operators).

Answer (score 1):

the answer to the question was:

```
public function salvar($name,$size,$id){

    $this->mongoNoSetOperator = '$push';

    // fixed array data structure
    $susp = array( 
        "_id" => $id,
        "images"=> array(
            array(
                'id' => new MongoId(),
                'name' => $name,
                'size' => $size
            )
        )
     );

    return $this->save($susp);
}
```

Note: Thank Garamon from github, by clear and objective answers.